# UITableViewController functionality in normal UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm currently having a `UITableView` added to a `UIView` managed by a normal `UIViewController` (all defined in IB)
Now I want to add some of the `UITableViewController` functionality to this `UITableView` (automatic scrolling when textfield is selected, refreshcontrol managed, auto insets etc.). How can I manage this without using a `UITableViewController` for the whole layout (I want to add other stuff to my view too so `UITableViewController` isn't a option) and without recreating the entire functionality by myself?

Comment: refresh control you can add using UIRefreshControl, the other behaviour should be accessible by implementing the UITableView delegate methods I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to set up a `UITableViewController` for a already initialized `UITableView` even if you're using a normal `UIViewController` to manage the view containing it.
Create a `UITableViewController`, set the already existing `UITableView` as the managed tableview and then add it as a child `UIViewController` to your current viewcontroller.

Example (for use in the `viewDidLoad` method):

```
UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:yourTableView.style];
tableViewController.tableView = yourTableView;
[self addChildViewController:tableViewController];
```

This will add all the functionality you want while still supporting the addition of more components to your view.

Comment: I'll just leave [objc.io article](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/table-views.html) here (;

Answer (score 0):

If you do go with a regular view controller, just remember to flash the scroll bars and deselect the currently selected row in the appropriate places. This is a pet peeve of mine. `UITableViewController` does this by default:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView flashScrollIndicators];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
                      animated:animated];
}
```